# SQL ACCESS - Dividing rows by a specific total over time

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a SQL database to which I connect with Access.

The data is structured as follows:

```
Date    ELEMENT     VALUE
01-2010 ElementA    12
01-2010 ElementB    43
01-2010 ElementC    53
01-2010 ElementD    24
01-2010 El_Divisor  120
02-2010 ElementA    54
02-2010 ElementB    32
02-2010 ElementC    48
02-2010 ElementD    21
02-2010 El_Divisor  130
etc etc....
```

I will need to obtain, for each point in time, each element divided by "ElementDivisor", i.e.

```
Date    ELEMENT     VALUE
01-2010 ElementA    = 12 / 120
01-2010 ElementB    = 43 / 120
01-2010 ElementC    = 53 / 120
01-2010 ElementD    = 24 / 120
01-2010 El_Divisor  = 120 / 120 = 1
02-2010 ElementA    = 54 / 130
02-2010 ElementB    = 32 / 130
02-2010 ElementC    = 48 / 130
02-2010 ElementD    = 21 / 130
02-2010 El_Divisor  = 130 / 130 = 1
etc etc....
```

Note: the "El_Divisor" is NOT the total of all the other elements.
At the moment I am using a very not elegant multiple cross-tab system, which is very sub-optimal.

Anyone has an idea?
Ideas in other SQL-programs are very welcome as well.

Many thanks

Comment: So basically each month/year pair would have a series of elements, and a matching divisor record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this solution:

```
Select
  tbl_Elements.[Date],
  tbl_Elements.Element,
  tbl_Elements.[Value] / tbl_Elements_1.[Value]
From
  tbl_Elements
    INNER JOIN
  tbl_Elements tbl_Elements_1
    ON tbl_Elements.Date = tbl_Elements_1.Date
Where
  tbl_Elements.Element <> "El_Divisor"
  AND tbl_Elements_1.Element = "El_Divisor"
```

you could remove `tbl_Elements.Element <> "El_Divisor"` if you want to see the divisor divided by itself.

Comment: Tested and works! Slightly more straightforward, I'm going to use this one.
Thanks to everyone, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works in Access, might have to put the inner selects into views:

```
Select
  v.[Date],
  v.Element,
  v.[Value] / d.[Value] As [Value]
From (
  Select
    e.[Date], e.[Value]
  From
    Elements e
  Where
    e.Element = 'El_Divisor'
 ) As d Inner Join (
   Select
     e.[Date], e.Element, e.[Value]
   From
     Elements e
   Where
     e.Element <> 'El_Divisor' -- take this out if you want to see the El_Divisor/El_Divisor row
 ) as v
   On d.[Date] = v.[Date]
```

Edit - fixed as per Remou's suggestions

Comment: Looks good to me for Access, except that date and value are reserved words, so [date], [value] or d.date and `e.Element != 'El_Divisor'` should be `e.Element <> 'El_Divisor'`

Comment: @Remou - Thanks, fixed this, and noticed I was using the wrong alias for the outer select.